# How does the 'apt edit-sources' work?

Tags: apt

For the `apt` command, the `edit-sources` option exists.

According to `apt --help`, it is indicated:

```
edit-sources - edit the source information file
```

And according to [`man apt`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/apt.8.html), it is indicated:

```
edit-sources (work-in-progress)
    edit-sources lets you edit your sources.list(5) files in your preferred text editor while also providing basic sanity checks.
```

I couldn't find a tutorial through the web for how to use this option though. Some guidance is appreciated.

Comment: It opens /etc/apt/sources.list in an editor. Exactly like the manpage says. It might be easiest to understand if you simply try it.

Comment: Thanks - It let me to choice 3 editors, I selected nano. But why exists this option? I mean the  `sources.list` can be edited by hand by other editor, right? such as `vim`

Comment: @ManuelJordan Yes, you can edit the `sources.list` manually. The option is provided as a shortcut with the additional benefit of providing sanity checks, as also stated in the `man apt` part you provided in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results of `sudo apt edit-sources` in my Ubuntu 22.04 are as follows:

```
Select an editor. To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  2. /usr/bin/vim.tiny
  3. /usr/bin/emacs
  4. /bin/ed
```

All of the listed editors are free software, so it's appropriate to give users of edit-sources an extra amount of software freedom. As the output of `sudo apt edit-sources` says, nano is the easiest and most Ubuntu users would be more comfortable with nano, but advanced Ubuntu users might prefer to use a more full-featured editor such as Vim or Emacs, especially if they routinely use that editor anyway.

Comment: In my case it shows 3 options, by your side 4 ... interesting

Comment: @ManuelJordan You probably don't have `emacs` installed.